# Remove or customize left sidebar tips in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

How can I remove or customize the left sidebar tips in Visual Studio 2022 ?
(them are visible in C# projects, with both Professional or Enterprise VS versions)

The annoying tip is the one that indicates that the class implements an interface.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey it is a bit late but i'm writing this for whoever come to this issue.
[image: issue]

you can uncheck the show inheritence margin in C#>Advanced tab.